# Vectorize loop codes

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vectorization, rstudio-server

I have a number of nested for and if loops code which I am applying to different datasets which increase by 10 folds.
The code works perfectly but takes very long to run (currently 10 days for a dataset with a length of 310). I am running the code on the Rstudio server on localhost. I would like to vectorize this but with the many nested for and if loops, I am even sure of where to start. I need to run 370 similar codes, hence my request for help.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Here is the code (my apologies, the code is quiet lengthy):

```
library(e1071)
library(mcga)

ptm <- proc.time()

data<-read.csv("apr_data2.csv",header=TRUE)
n<-nrow(data)
frag<-data[(n-29):n,]
## subset daily data greater than zero
frag2<-frag[frag$V4>0.1,]

 ## fragments from subset data
frag3<-frag[,5:28]/frag[,4]

## daily data without corresponding sub-hourly data
data_2D = data$V4 
num2 = 1:length(data_2D)

## daily data with corresponding sub-hourly data
total<- frag$V4 
num = 1:length(total)

##wet or dry state indicator
status1<-ifelse(frag$V4>=0.1,1,0) 
status2<-ifelse(data$V4>=0.1,1,0)

## classes for sampling
break99<-c(0.1,1,10,25,Inf)

##preallocate space for disaggregated data
Disagg_data<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(data_2D),ncol=24)) 

##prealocate space for simulation runs
runs = 100
final<-matrix(NA,nrow=length(data_2D)*ncol(Disagg_data),ncol = runs)

## begin simulation runs
for (sim in 1:runs){

## put daily data with corresponding sub-daily data into classes
for (k in 2:(length(total)-1)){
    if (is.na(total[k])) next
    if (total[k]>0){
      for (i in 1:(length(break99)-1)){
        if (total[k]>=break99[i]&total[k]<break99[i+1]){
          oxt<-num[total>=break99[i]&total<break99[i+1]]
          oxt<-oxt[oxt!=1 & oxt!=length(total)]

}
}
}
}

## put daily data to be disaggregated into classes
for (t in 2:(length(data_2D)-1)){
    if (is.na(data_2D[t])) next
    if (data_2D[t]>0){
      for (i in 1:(length(break99)-1)){
        if (data_2D[t]>=break99[i]&data_2D[t]<break99[i+1]){
          oyt<-num2[data_2D>=break99[i]&data_2D<break99[i+1]]
          oyt<-oyt[oyt!=1 & oyt!=length(data_2D)]

}
}
}
}

## identify days with matching wetness 
## sample 2 and use crossover algorithm to create 2 new fragments
## add new fragments and sample one to disaggregate daily data
for (k in 2:(length(total)-1)){
for (t in 2:(length(data_2D)-1)){
    if (length(oxt[!is.na(oxt)])>1){
     if (length(oyt[!is.na(oyt)])>1){
      if (length(oxt[!is.na(oxt)&status1[oxt-1]==status1[k-1]&status1[oxt+1]==status1[k+1]])&length(oyt[!is.na(oyt)&status2[oyt-1]==status2[t-1]&status2[oyt+1]==status2[t+1]])>=2){
         index<-sample(oxt[!is.na(oxt)&status1[oxt-1]==status1[k-1]&status1[oxt+1]==status1[k+1]],2)
         v1<-frag[index[1],5:28]/frag[index[1],4]
         v2<-frag[index[2],5:28]/frag[index[2],4]
       cut<-sample(1:24,1)
        child<-OnePointCrossOverOnDoublesUsingBytes(unlist(v1),unlist(v2),cut)
        child1<-child[[1]]/sum(child[[1]]) 
        child2<-child[[2]]/sum(child[[2]])
          combine<-rbind(v1,v2,child1,child2)
          select_hourly_vector<-combine[sample(nrow(combine),1),]
          Disagg_data[t,1:24]<-data_2D[t]*select_hourly_vector

## when matched fragments is less than 2
      if (length(oxt[!is.na(oxt)&status1[oxt-1]==status1[k-1]&status1[oxt+1]==status1[k+1]])&length(oyt[!is.na(oyt)&status2[oyt-1]==status2[t-1]&status2[oyt+1]==status2[t+1]])==1){
         index<-sample(oxt[!is.na(oxt)&status1[oxt-1]==status1[k-1]&status1[oxt+1]==status1[k+1]],1)
         select_hourly_vector<-frag[index,5:28]/frag[index,4]
          Disagg_data[t,1:24]<-data_2D[t]*select_hourly_vector

## when there are no matched fragments, any fragment is sampled and used to disaggregated the daily data
   if (length(oxt[!is.na(oxt)&status1[oxt-1]==status1[k-1]&status1[oxt+1]==status1[k+1]])&length(oyt[!is.na(oyt)&status2[oyt-1]==status2[t-1]&status2[oyt+1]==status2[t+1]])==0){
       index<-sample(length(total),1)
       select_hourly_vector<-frag[index,5:28]/frag[index,4]
        Disagg_data[t,1:24]<-data_2D[t]*select_hourly_vector
}
}   
}
}
}
}
}

 final[,sim] = as.vector(t(Disagg_data))
}

write.csv(final,"onepoint apr 10yrs.csv")

proc.time() - ptm


structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    V2 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), V3 = c(999L, 
    999L, 999L, 999L, 999L, 999L, 999L, 999L, 999L, 999L), V4 = c(0.200000002, 
    2.500000025, 11.10000011, 32.80000049, 10.70000013, 3.600000041, 
    5.700000089, 57.50000089, 0, 14.10000021), X1 = c(0, 0, 0.200000002, 
    0.100000001, 0, 0.200000002, 0, 0, 0, 0), X2 = c(0, 0, 0.100000001, 
    0, 0, 0.100000001, 0, 0, 0, 0), X3 = c(0, 0, 0.100000001, 
    0.100000001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X4 = c(0, 0, 0.200000002, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X5 = c(0, 0, 0.200000002, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), X6 = c(0, 0, 0.100000001, 0, 0, 0, 1.000000015, 
    0, 0, 0), X7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.100000001, 0.100000001, 
    0, 0, 0), X8 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X9 = c(0, 
    0, 0.100000001, 0, 0, 0.100000001, 0, 0.200000002, 0, 0), 
    X10 = c(0, 0, 0.300000004, 0.100000001, 0, 0, 0, 0.100000001, 
    0, 0), X11 = c(0, 0, 0.100000001, 0.200000003, 0, 0.200000003, 
    0, 0.300000004, 0, 0), X12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.70000001, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.900000013, 0, 0), X13 = c(0, 0, 0, 1.300000019, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.900000013, 0, 0), X14 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.500000007, 0, 0, 
    0, 1.40000002, 0, 0), X15 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.500000007, 0, 0, 
    0, 1.500000022, 0, 0.200000003), X16 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.100000001, 
    0, 0, 0, 1.700000025, 0, 0.400000006), X17 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.100000001, 
    0, 0, 0, 1.200000018, 0, 0.600000009), X18 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.70000001, 
    0.200000002, 0, 0, 0.200000003, 0, 0.500000007), X19 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0.100000001, 0.300000004, 0, 0, 0.100000001, 0, 0.800000012
    ), X20 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.200000003, 0.200000002, 0, 0, 0.200000002, 
    0, 0.100000001), X21 = c(0, 0, 0.100000001, 0, 0.100000001, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X22 = c(0, 0, 0.200000002, 0, 0.400000006, 
    0, 0, 0.100000001, 0, 0), X23 = c(0, 0.100000001, 0, 0, 0.500000007, 
    0, 0, 0.200000002, 0, 0), X24 = c(0, 0, 0.100000001, 0, 0.300000004, 
    0, 0, 0.200000003, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A good start would be to profile this code so you could tell which parts take the longest. You can do that by using `profvis`. Take a look at this reference https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/. You can test it out using maybe just a fragment of your original dataset, so you don't take 10 days to test it. Also, if you could provide some example data that would be great for us to help you.

Comment: On a side note, try to break your problem into smaller problems. Like you said, the code is quite long and there is a lot going on.

Comment: @eduardokapp Thanks for the suggestion. I will give try it out. I have provided the sample dataset in the link below the code

Comment: you're welcome! You see, that's not good practice here on stack overflow. Usually we try to provide a pure-simple reproducible dataset with some code to generate it. You can generate such code by using `ddput(your_data_set)`, give it a try! I suggest you get the first like 10 rows of your data and apply this.

Comment: @eduardokapp my apologies for that. I have added a subset of the data as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it as soon as possible.

Comment: @eduardokapp Thanks. I run the profvis like you suggested and found that there are 3 particular sections within the loop that take the most time.

Comment: 1. Are you sure the code works perfectly? You are testing for the condition (cnd) `length(oxt[!is.na(oxt)&status1[oxt-1]==status1[k-1]&status1[oxt+1]==status1[k+1]])&length(oyt[!is.na(oyt)&status2[oyt-1]==status2[t-1]&status2[oyt+1]==status2[t+1]])==1` within a `cnd >=2` if clause, etc.. These variables do not appear to change in between, so these tests will never be TRUE. 2. Calculate those two subsets once per loop and reuse them for length tests and sampling). 3. Wrap the code repeated 100x into a function and run it in parallel for easy speed improvement (multiple cores required).

Comment: @user12728748 thanks for the suggestions. What 2 subsets are you referring to?

Comment: `oxt[!is.na(oxt)&status1[oxt-1]==status1[k-1]&status1[oxt+1]==status1[k+1]]` and `oyt[!is.na(oyt)&status2[oyt-1]==status2[t-1]&status2[oyt+1]==status2[t+1]]`

Comment: @user12728748 got it. Thanks.